# Primes and infinite primes of the form $29 + 72k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

can you give the validity or proof of the following statements of my observations on Primes?

$(1)$ For a positive integer $k$, there exists infinitely many primes of the form $29 + 72k$.
$(2)$ If the cited above $(1)$ is true, then the following is true. That is:
Let $ p = 29+72k$ (where $p$ is prime) and we get always or infinitely many primes $q$ by considering $q = (p+1)/6$

Comment: The first is an instance of Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progression, which you should look up. The second, the "always" part is surely false. The "infinitely many" part is an instance of a notorious unsolved problem.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson! can you prove my (1) by using Dirichlet's theorem?

Comment: @raja_narasimha Have you read the statement of [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)? It would require more effort *not* to prove (1) using that.

Comment: @Erick, you've given me the idea for a new type of homework question: "Using such-and-such theorem, *don't* prove such-and-such a result."

Comment: @ErickWong!I read the statement of Dirichlet's theorem. But, I don't know that how this is related to my (1). If yes, can you justify as much as possible?

Comment: You must have read the statement of Seymour Dirichlet's Theorem, which says that if $\gcd(a,b)\gt1$ then there are only finitely many primes of the form $ak+b$. Seymour wasn't much good at math --- it's the theorem of his older brother, Gustav, that you want. What exactly is the statement of the theorem you found?

Answer (score 1):

(1) is an instance of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). At the [elementary-number-theory](/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory) level you aren't expected to prove this, just say that you're using it.

(2) is not known to be true, though it would follow from various unproven conjectures like [Dickson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson's_conjecture).